# drupal back one step in the breadrumbs

Tags: drupal, navigation, drupal-6, back

I need to have a back button but I need it to jump to the previous link in the breadcrumb

so if my breadcrumb is

home > about me > work experience > business

I am  on the business page the back will point to 'work experience', on the  'work experience' page the back button will point to 'about me'

I am looking for a drupal solution not a JavaScript one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, since breadcrumbs system is pretty fucked up in D7, JS solution isn't that bad at all. Easy and predictable at least.

For Drupal solution - you need to override Breadcrumbs theme function in your theme template.php,
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_breadcrumb/7
you can override theme function by simply implementing your theme_breadcrumbs and do what's needed there.